# Using hashcode() modulus length of the array returns with null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashcode

I'm trying to use the hashcode of a string and the modulus the length of a array to get the index of where it should be stored for a hash table. Here is where I think I'm messing it up:

Array declaration and constructor:

```
private Bucket[] list;

public Hash() {
    list = new Bucket[8];
}
```

And the actual code:

```
//if such a key exists already, you should replace its value
public void insert(String key, Textbook value) {
    rehash();
    if(list[key.hashCode()%list.length].insert(key, value)) size++;
}

//checks if the key exists
public boolean contains(String key) {
    return (list[key.hashCode()%list.length] != null) ? list[key.hashCode()%list.length].contains(key) : false;
}

public void remove(String key) {
    if(list[key.hashCode()%list.length].remove(key)) size --;
}
```

The insert and remove return null pointers and the contains method returns always returns false.

What I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 list = new Bucket[8];
```

Does not allocate any `Bucket` object, it only allocates an array full with `null` values.

Thus, `list[key.hashCode()%list.length] == null` (explains why `contains()` returns `null`, and `list[key.hashCode()%list.length].remove(...)` or `list[key.hashCode()%list.length].insert(...)` causes you to try and access `null`, which in its turn causes NPE).

You will also have to iterate the array and initialize every element with non null value, using `Bucket`'s constructor or some factory method.